# How do I approach a javascript/clojurescript wrapper library for an api?

Tags: javascript, ajax, clojurescript

I'm primarily a Python developer, but I've been trying to learn Clojure/ClojureScript lately. As practice, I want to write a ClojureScript wrapper for Reddit's API.

Most of my confusion is due to the asynchronous nature of Javascript. Since AJAX functions don't actually return the response from the API, how do I write the wrapper so it works somewhat similarly to synchronous server-side requests?

Or is this not possible at all, and I have to use callbacks for each call to the API in my app (and thus a wrapper library would be pointless)?

Are there similar libraries out there I can reference? (Javascript/ClojureScript)

Comment: http://brianmckenna.org/blog/cps_transform_js

Comment: Also https://github.com/gregspurrier/to-be-continued

Comment: You can opt to make you AJAX call synchronously, would that do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make synchronous XHR requests, but it's not idiomatic. Javascript (and Clojurescript by extension) uses a single-threaded execution model, so long-running calls are typically asynchronous to avoid blocking execution of other parts of the application. If you were writing a wrapper for a synchronous API you would typically add a callback parameter to each API method (and don't forget to provide some form of error handling).

Regarding your specific question, accessing the reddit API from a browser almost certainly violate [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy): you can typically only make AJAX requests to the domain that served the original Javascript. Usually when you want to provide client-side (browser-based) access to a third-party service you do this by proxying the client requests through your server. The server should ensure that it only proxies requests from authorised clients. If you decided to take this route, you'd make an asynchronous request from your browser using clojurescript to your webserver (presumably running clojure), which would authenticate the request, then make a synchronous request to the reddit API and return the result to the client. When the response is ready the client will invoke the callback and your code will receive the result.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the 2nd paragraph, that would result in reddit's API eventually blocking my server if it exceeds the limits? How do reddit clients handle this issue? (e.g. Alien Blue for iOS) Or they don't have this issue since they aren't browser-based.

Comment: Yes, reddit's API might block your server if you exceed their threshold. If you end up writing a popular service you might be able to contact them and have them increase the limit your your service. Apps aren't subject to these limits as they don't run within a browser sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is known to most programming languages as "futures". JavaScript libraries [that implement such things](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) generally refer to futures as "promises".

In Python there are several libraries that implement futures.  The most well known are [`Twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com) and [`Tornado`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/), however, [`Tulip`](https://code.google.com/p/tulip/) is an up-and-coming library that will [most likely land as the default event loop implementation for Python 3.4](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/).

The same story is true in JavaScript.  [Many](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) [popular](https://github.com/cujojs/when) [libraries](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js) ([jQuery included](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)) provide an implementation of futures, letting you turn this:

```
function makeTwoAsyncCalls(errorCallback, successCallback) {
    ajaxRequest(errorCallback, function onSuccess(data) {
       processWithWebWorker(errorCallback, successCallback);
    });
}
```

into this:

```
function doWorkAsync(errorCallback, successCallback) {
    return ajaxRequest()
        .then(processWithWebWorker)
        .then(successCallback)
        .fail(errorCallback);
}
```

Comment: Clojure(script) provides futures as a language feature but they're not really what you want for XHR requests as they will block until the future is available.